# Finding the min of a column across multiple lists in python

Tags: python, list, minimum

I need to find the minimum and maximum of a given a column from a csv file and currently the value is a string but I need it to be an integer, right now my output after I have split all the lines into lists looks like this

```
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '14/06/2020', '390', '10\n']
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '11/06/2020', '364', '27\n']
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '12/06/2020', '802', '28\n']
['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '13/06/2020', '497', '24\n']
```

And from that line along with its many others I want to find the minimum of the
5th column and currently when I do

```
min(column[4])
```

It just gives the min of each individual list which is just the number in that column rather than grouping them all up and getting that minimum.

P.S: I am very new to python and coding in general, I also have to do this without any importing of modules.

For you Azro.

```
def main(csvfile,country,analysis):
infile = csvfile
datafile = open(infile, "r")
country = country.capitalize()     
if analysis == "statistics":
    for line in datafile.readlines():
        column = line.split(",")
        if column[2] == country:
```

Comment: You are using the word column. Are we talking about data frames our lists?

Comment: Can you share the code that reads the data and builds the lists ?

Comment: I was thinking do i need to convert that into integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `pandas` that allows to read csv file and manipulate them as `DataFrame`, then it's very easy to retrieve a `min/max` from a column

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=',')

mini = df['colName'].min()
maxi = df['colName'].max()
print(mini, maxi)
```

---

Then if you have already read your data in a list of lists, you max use builtin `min` and `max`

```
# use rstrip() when reading line, to remove leading \n
values = [
    ['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '14/06/2020', '390', '10'],
    ['FRA', 'Europe', 'France', '14/06/2020', '395', '10']
]

mini = min(values, key=lambda x: int(x[4]))[4]
maxi = max(values, key=lambda x: int(x[4]))[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the library [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html) and especially the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) class. This is probably the go-to method for handling .csv files and tabular data in general.

Essentially, your code would be something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv') # Construct a DataFrame from a csv file
print(df.columns) # check to see which column names the dataframe has
print(df['My Column'].min())
print(df['My Column'].max())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are shorter ways to do this. But this example goes step by step:

```
# After you read a CSV file, you'll have a bunch of rows.
rows = [
    ['A', '390', '...'],
    ['B', '750', '...'],
    ['C', '207', '...'],
]

# Grab a column that you want.
col = [row[1] for row in rows]

# Convert strings to integers.
vals = [int(s) for s in col]

# Print max.
print(max(vals))
```